# Using node.js & async.js: series executing in the wrong order?

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I am using express and async.js for a node application. I have this code in my app.js:

```
var resultObject = {};

app.get('/average', function(req, res) {
  async.series([
    function(callback) {
  //This does some complex computations and updates the resultObject
      routes.avg(req.query.url, resultObject);
      console.log('1');
      callback();
    }
    ,
    function(callback) { 
      res.send(resultObject);
      console.log('2');
      callback();
    }
  ]);
});
```

The problem is that the res.send(...) fires before the complex computation in the first function finishes. Therefore, the object sent is empty. Is there some error in my code, or am I not using async.js correctly?

Comment: according to the code you pasted, resultObject would be empty anyway, unless routes.avg modifies it. do you have the rest of your code available? It doesn't seem plausible that the methods are being executed out of order.

Comment: That's exactly what it does, it modifies the resultObject. The problem is that the res.send() fires before the function that modifies the object has finished its calculations.

Comment: is routes.avg an asynchronous method?

Comment: Yes. I wonder if the problem is that the method is exported and not called directly in app.js with a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, the problem is that your `routes.avg` method is asynchronous. This means that the method gets executed but doesn't block the program from continuing, which means that the 2nd closure in your series is being called almost immediately after the 1st one.

The problem isn't that the closures in the `async.series` call are being called out of order, it's that there's nothing that keeps your `callback` in closure 1 from being executed before `routes.avg` is finished.

To fix this, you could pass your `callback` into your `routes.avg` call, and edit the `routes.avg` method so that it calls the callback closure when all the calculation is done. That way, the 2nd closure in your series will not be executed until the `callback` passed to closure 1 is called by the `routes.avg` method.

If you don't have access to change the `routes.avg` method, then you have to find another way to detect when it's done it's work before you call the `callback` param passed to closure 1 from async.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    routes.avg(req.query.url, resultObject);
    console.log('1');
    callback();
  },
  function(callback) { 
    console.log('2');
    callback();
  }
],
function(err, results){
   if(!err)
     res.send(resultObject);
   else
     //do something here for error?
});
```

Comment: There would be no use for invoking the second function at all then. Plus, this doesn't work, the behavious is still that which I described above.